# Bash terminal colors in integrated terminal in VS Code

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm on a windows 10 machine and I recently installed VS Code to use instead of Sublime Text 3. I changed the integrated terminal in VS Code to default to git Bash. That is working just fine now but I seemed to have lost my color coding for files and directories. I tried adding `eval "$(dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS)"` to my .bash_profile but it still doesn't work in the integrated terminal, however if I open Bash externally all of my colors are still there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get colors to work in my Bash integrated terminal in VSCode by configuring my `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\bash.bashrc` file. I found that simply using `eval "$(dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS)"` alone was not sufficient. At the top of my `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\DIR_COLORS` file I saw this:

```
# Configuration file for dircolors, a utility to help you set the
# LS_COLORS environment variable used by GNU ls with the --color option.
```

So I tested using `ls --color` and it worked! I then created the following aliases in bash.bashrc:

```
alias ls='ls --color' # list with color
alias la='ls -alF'    # list all
```

I also found that you can customize the colors (and composition) of the Bash prompt by editing the `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh` file and including `shopt -q login_shell || . /etc/profile.d/git-prompt.sh` in bash.bashrc.

I can't explain why the ls alias is needed for the integrated terminal but now I'm happy since my colors now match the external terminal.

Comment: Thank you! An alias with '--color' did it for me.

```alias ls='ls --color' # list with color```

Answer (score 3):

### Solve Windows vscode Open Git Bash No Color

1. Download [Ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon)
2. After unzipping, rename this folder to `ANSICON` and move it to `C:\ Program Files \`.
3. Modify the VSCode settings:

   ```
    // old config:
    {
        ...

        "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\ANSICON\\x64\\ansicon.exe",
        "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
            "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe",
            "--login",
            "-i"
        ]
    }

    // new config with after 2021/05:

    {
        ...

        "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
        "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
            "Git Bash": {
                "path": "C:\\Program Files\\ANSICON\\x64\\ansicon.exe",
                "args": ["C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe", "--login", "-i"]
            }
        },
    }
   ```
4. Reopen the terminal.

Comment: This worked for me, but now I cannot scroll up the console output anymore. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Normal "Git Bash" works for me in VSC on Windows. But if I wrap it with `ansicon.exe` as suggested in your answer, then I can't debug from within VSC any more. Apparently it starts interpreting the backslashes as escape characters. The terminal output I am getting is: `$  c:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.10.0\adapter\codelldb.exe terminal-agent --connect=61727`   
`bash: c:Usersusername.vscodeextensionsvadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.10.0adaptercodelldb.exe: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

VSCode team have removed customizing colors from user settings page. Currently using the themes is the only way to customize terminal colors in VSCode. For more information check out issue [#6766](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6766).

Answer copied from : 
[Color theme for VS Code integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS, fire Terminal App, then :

```
nano .zshrc
```

#Add these lines

```
alias ls='ls --color' # list with color
alias la='ls -alF'    # list all
```

Command W, Y to save file