# Color theme for VS Code integrated terminal

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

Can we change color settings of VS Code Integrated Terminal? Mine looks dull with just white.

[image]

Comment: [Here's a useful theme generator](https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term/#/) to modify your `"workbench.colorCustomizations"` in settings.json

Comment: Different background color and customization *per* terminal window would be nice.

Comment: To customize the terminal find highlight color  add `"terminal.selectionBackground": "#e26cffcb",` on the dark theme. See [vscode-terminal-change-the-find-highlight-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776940/vscode-terminal-change-the-find-highlight-color?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Here is a video that shows how to change the terminal colors in vscode https://youtu.be/p4h-5B8k2NY

Answer (score 351, accepted):

You can actually modify your user settings and edit each colour individually by adding the following to the user settings.

1. Open user settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
2. Search for `workbench` and select `Edit in settings.json` under `Color Customizations`

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations" : {
    "terminal.foreground" : "#00FD61",
    "terminal.background" : "#383737"
}
```

For more on what colors you can edit you can find out [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#integrated-terminal-colors).

Comment: I believe they removed this functionality.  Are you certain this still works in the latest version?

Comment: It's currently working for me, my VSCode version is 1.17.2 (which is the latest)

Comment: You're right.  Odd. They said it was removed, but it is there. Just tried it myself and it worked.  I was disappointed that they said it was removed. Glad to see that's not the case.

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer. still works in build 1.18

Comment: This works correctly! I also want to learn how to get contrast colors in terminal though!

Comment: Still works as of 1.24.0.  I think part of the confusion is that you can't search for `terminal.background` in settings (`'workbench.colorCustomizations': {}` is the default), so it seems like a missing feature at first glance.

Comment: It worked for me, but weirdly enough, I had to set `"workbench.colorCustomizations": { "terminal.ansiBlack": "#cccccc" }` and now I can read what's on the terminal (with a dark theme).

Comment: Bob and Pman - I believe you guys and accepting this as the answer.

Comment: I didn't have "workbench.colorCustomizations" in my settings.json. After adding that along with the above, it worked for me.

Comment: as i'm 40 next year, i appreciate your example which makes the VS Code terminal like my very first computer the Amstrad CPC 464 :)

Comment: How can I change the color of the username only? Can't find any commands about that

Comment: I confirm it also works in the latest OpenVSCode Server.

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that you can scope the override to a specific theme by adding "[themeName]": { <put the overrides here> } under `workbench.colorCustomizations` i.e. the themeName must be withing square brackets.

Answer (score 120):

In case you are color picky,  use this code to customize every segment.

Step 1:
Open user settings

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Step 2:
Search for "workbench: color customizations" and select Edit in settings.json.
Page the following code inside existing {} and customize as you like.

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.background":"#131212",
    "terminal.foreground":"#dddad6",
    "terminal.ansiBlack":"#1D2021",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlack":"#665C54",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlue":"#0D6678",
    "terminal.ansiBrightCyan":"#8BA59B",
    "terminal.ansiBrightGreen":"#237e02",
    "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta":"#8F4673",
    "terminal.ansiBrightRed":"#FB543F",
    "terminal.ansiBrightWhite":"#FDF4C1",
    "terminal.ansiBrightYellow":"#FAC03B",
    "terminal.ansiBlue":"#00a1f9",
    "terminal.ansiCyan":"#8BA59B",
    "terminal.ansiGreen":"#95C085",
    "terminal.ansiMagenta":"#8F4673",
    "terminal.ansiRed":"#FB543F",
    "terminal.ansiWhite":"#A89984",
    "terminal.ansiYellow":"#FAC03B"
},
```

Resource: This site has VS Code themes you can copy/paste in settings. https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term/#/

Comment: Thanks! Blue is missing: e.g. `"terminal.ansiBlue":"#00a1f9"`

Comment: This website provides a bunch of terminal themes customizations that you can copy/paste into your settings: https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term/

Comment: Thanks. 
It's not a matter of being color picky... it's more like, some of these default colors don't work for everyone - red on black background ? Can barely see... there are other people on my team who have trouble seeing for example, green.
So this will help everyone.. and yeah, I had red on black :-)

Comment: If you are a visual learner here is a short video https://youtu.be/rYb_WpOc0UY

Answer (score 47):

VSCode comes with in-built color themes which can be used to change the colors of the editor and the terminal.

- For changing the color theme press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in windows/ubuntu or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on mac.
- Alternatively you can open **command palette** by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in windows/ubuntu or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on mac and type `color`. Select `preferences: color theme` from the options, to select your favourite color.
- You can also install more themes from the extensions menu on the left bar. just search `category:themes` to install your favourite themes. (If you need to sort the themes by installs search `category:themes @sort:installs`)

**Edit** - for manually editing colors in terminal

VSCode team have removed customizing colors from user settings page. Currently using the themes is the only way to customize terminal colors in VSCode. For more information check out [issue #6766](http://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6766)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the global themes have minimal impact on the terminal window, only affecting background and foreground color in a very broad sense.  OP and I were looking to colorize the prompt, input command, and output independently, not just change between white-on-black and black-on-white.  Know of a way to gain more control over the terminal text colors?

Comment: Seems like they removed customizing colors from user settings page. Currently using the themes seems to be the only way to customize terminal colors in VSCode. check out https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6766

Comment: It's unfortunate that that the answer appears to be that it currently isn't supported, but it's useful to know nonetheless.  I'll assign you the bounty.  Thanks for tracking this down.

Comment: From what I can tell, it *is* still in there to customize from the settings.  Open settings and look for 'workbench.colorCustomizations'

Comment: This is to change the global color theme and doesnt affect the integrated terminal

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, other answer doesnt work anymore +1

Comment: @kjhughes - I was looking for how to colorize the prompt as well. Found that at least on a Mac, adding export PS1="\[\e[0;34m\]\u\[\e[0;32m\]@\[\e[0;36m\]\w \[\e[0;37m\]\@ \[\e[0;35m\]$ \[\e[0m\]" to my ~/.bashrc and then sourcing that colorizes the prompt.

Answer (score 35):

Add `workbench.colorCustomizations` to user settings

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "terminal.background":"#FEFBEC",
  "terminal.foreground":"#6E6B5E",
  ...
}
```

Check https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term for some presets.

Comment: the interactive presets site is a fantastic resource

Answer (score 14):

The best colors I've found --which aside from being so beautiful, are very easy to look at too and do not boil my eyes-- are the ones I've found listed in this GitHub repository: **[VSCode Snazzy](https://github.com/Tyriar/vscode-snazzy)**

**Very Easy Installation**:

> Copy the contents of [snazzy.json](https://github.com/Tyriar/vscode-snazzy/blob/b155eb74098971c3daca73942d7d626c8bcc2ec9/snazzy.json) into your VS Code "settings.json" file.

(In case you don't know how to open the "settings.json" file, first hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then write *Preferences: open settings(JSON)* and hit enter).

---

**_Notice**:_ For those who have tried [ColorTool](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal/tree/master/src/tools/ColorTool) and it works outside VSCode but not inside VSCode, you've made no mistakes in implementing it, that's just [a decision of VSCode developers](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45705#issuecomment-388448816) for the VSCode's terminal to be colored independently.

Answer (score 12):

Go to the **settings of VSCode**

On **Windows/Linux** - *File > Preferences > Settings or  Shortcut(ctrl,)*

On **macOS** - *Code > Preferences > Settings or Shortcut (⌘,) or Search (⇧⌘P) → “Preferences: Open Settings”*

Search for **"workbench: color customizations"** and open the **settings.json** file

You can see workbench.colorCustomizations as empty if you are editing it for the first time,

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
}
```

Edit or Paste your configuration under workbench.colorCustomizations

Fill it with your customized options,
I sharing **Isotope** theme here

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.background":"#000000",
    "terminal.foreground":"#D0D0D0",
    "terminalCursor.background":"#D0D0D0",
    "terminalCursor.foreground":"#D0D0D0",
    "terminal.ansiBlack":"#000000",
    "terminal.ansiBlue":"#0066FF",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlack":"#808080",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlue":"#0066FF",
    "terminal.ansiBrightCyan":"#00FFFF",
    "terminal.ansiBrightGreen":"#33FF00",
    "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta":"#CC00FF",
    "terminal.ansiBrightRed":"#FF0000",
    "terminal.ansiBrightWhite":"#FFFFFF",
    "terminal.ansiBrightYellow":"#FF0099",
    "terminal.ansiCyan":"#00FFFF",
    "terminal.ansiGreen":"#33FF00",
    "terminal.ansiMagenta":"#CC00FF",
    "terminal.ansiRed":"#FF0000",
    "terminal.ansiWhite":"#D0D0D0",
    "terminal.ansiYellow":"#FF0099"
}
```

Now you can able to see your changes in VS Code Terminal

For more themes => [Base16 Themes](https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term/#/)

For more customization => [VSCode Terminal Colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#integrated-terminal-colors)

Comment: Base16 Themes link is great

Comment: `terminalCursor.background` and `terminalCursor.foreground` shouldn't be the same colour. You can't see text if the cursor is over it. In my theme, I set `terminalCursor.background` the same as `terminal.background` and that works.

Answer (score 6):

if you want prebuilt theme for terminal
first check out this [link](https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term/#/)

copy the theme you want and in settings.json
add:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations":{
 //paste the copied theme  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use Oh My Zsh. It takes the dullness away and also have nice features.

Check the link here: https://ohmyz.sh/

Answer (score 2):

Check also VSCode 1.61 (Sept. 2021) with:

- [Issue 128228 "Support setting terminal color in TerminalOptions | ExtensionTerminalOptions"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128228)
- [PR 128856](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/128856)
- [commit ad59706](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/ad5970666d4cdf7d4bee61b7a461555b8860131d)

It adds:

```
    export interface TerminalOptions {
        /**
         * Supports all ThemeColor keys, terminal.ansi* is recommended for contrast/consistency
         */
        color?: ThemeColor;
    }
    export interface ExtensionTerminalOptions {
        /**
         * Supports all ThemeColor keys, terminal.ansi* is recommended for contrast/consistency
         */
        color?: ThemeColor;
    }
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what this looks like filled out, and where this needs to go? (or are these shell commands?)

Comment: @Sterling I don't have much beside what you can see in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128228#issuecomment-879163304

Answer (score 1):

On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings or Shortcut (⌘,) or Search (⇧⌘P) → “Preferences: Open Settings”

"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
}
and choose which color you want form here: https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term/#/

Answer (score 0):

Simply. You can go to 'File -> Preferences -> Color Theme' option in visual studio and change the color of you choice.

Comment: This does not change the text color of terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Gruvbox Dark color:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.background":"#252525",
    "terminal.foreground":"#ecdbb2",
    "terminal.ansiBlack":"#353535",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlack":"#a39586",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlue":"#94b3a8",
    "terminal.ansiBrightCyan":"#9dd08e",
    "terminal.ansiBrightGreen":"#c4c431",
    "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta":"#dc9aab",
    "terminal.ansiBrightRed":"#fe6142",
    "terminal.ansiBrightWhite":"#efe1bf",
    "terminal.ansiBrightYellow":"#fcc73c",
    "terminal.ansiBlue":"#549699",
    "terminal.ansiCyan":"#79aa7d",
    "terminal.ansiGreen":"#a8a521",
    "terminal.ansiMagenta":"#bf7897",
    "terminal.ansiRed":"#d73925",
    "terminal.ansiWhite":"#b7a996",
    "terminal.ansiYellow":"#dfa82a"
  },
```