# How to change vs code background for terminal progress

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find a setting to change this, but the background color drives me nuts in the VS Code editor terminal. I have terminal.background set to black and it does in fact set it to black, but when I run tns run android and get an error or warning it goes to this color and I can't seem to change it back.

[image]

Comment: I think this functionality was disabled. what version of vs code do you have? you may only be able to override the terminal settings through a theme. there's more info on the GitHub issue [#16766](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6766)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color theme for VS Code integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Just want to address this old question. I was experiencing, and have been largely ignoring, the seemingly configuration error for the VS Code terminal background color (in Windows).

**Solution:** Set the Windows Terminal default colors the same as the VS Code terminal colors.

Here's my black background settings for VS Code in the settings.json:

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations" : {
    "terminal.ansiBlue": "#ADADAD",
    "terminal.ansiBlack": "#424242",
    "terminal.background": "#121212",
    "terminal.foreground": "#DEDEDE"
    }
```

}

Matching the Windows Terminal default:

[Terminal Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77JQK.png)

[Background Color to Red:12 Green:12 Blue:12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9y1U.png)

**Background info:**
I got this figured out now I think. VS Code will be using the terminal default color settings. This means that the terminal colors defined in the VS code theme will be used overlaying the default color theme as set for the Windows CMD terminal.

This means that if the 2 colors, set in VS Code and Windows Terminal" are set differently, one will get the "blocky" result as shown in the post.