# How to see vscode terminal theme colors?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to see what colors from current theme vscode uses in integrated terminal to make my standard terminal looking the same as vscode.

EDIT:  I wrote how to SEE. Not how to OVERRIDE.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color theme for VS Code integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Developer: Generate color theme from current settings` command. This outputs a new theme file with all the current color values. The terminal colors are under `colors.terminal*`