# Color highlighting in VS Code integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash

When I run commands in Git Bash I get color coded output:

[image]

But when I use the integrated terminal in VS Code the output is plain white text. How can I get the same coloring?

[image]

This isn't specific to Git Bash.. cmd and PowerShell also lose color in the VS Code Terminal.

I've found other questions on changing the VS Code terminal color theme, but I'm asking about maintaining the useful color coding shown in my first picture - not just a uniform color for all text.

Comment: I'll delete my answer, it appears my answer and this question was a duplicate. There seems to be a better solution anyways that you can maintain in your bash profile. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56180624/how-to-change-font-color-of-text-in-vscode-integrated-terminal

Comment: @soulshined That's only for coloring the prompt, right? I want to retain all Git Bash color coding like the blue folders & white files from the `ls` command

Comment: You can change the foreground color (not the prompt) of your text (`terminal.foreground`) using color customizations. But the integrated terminal doesn’t have insight on context such as TM Scopes afaik

Comment: what's the output of `dircolors` in those two environments? Have either of them set anything for the `LS_COLORS` or `LS_OPTIONS` environment variables? What if you run `ls --color=auto` or `ls --color=always` in the VS Code integrated terminal?