# How to fix tinker color text?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, tinker

I'm using Visual Studio Code to coding but recently i have strange problem how can i fix that?

When i enter php artisan tinker the tinker text isn't as always i remember the color was blue but now its white.
also after use php artisan migrate and etc commands the result texts is white

I Uninstall Vscode completely with all appdata and extensions and anything related to that but nothing changed after install latest version the tinker color is still white

Entrance Text : Psy Shell v 0.9.9 by Justin this color is white now ! how can i fix that?
[image]

Comment: have you updated your os ?

Comment: no i turned off my update

Comment: maybe https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/tinker-lost-colors?page=1 related

Comment: Really is not any human in this planet to help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43436403/6945325 i think this is what you are looking for

Comment: that's not work for me you know this is not the answer because they manually change terminal text so if i change the white text to blue all white text turning to blue but this should dynamically changed by vscode

Comment: if you type in your vscode php artisan tinker you can see the text is blue psyshell .... and you have not any customize color in your setting.json

Comment: https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/wiki/Config-options maybe related ?

Comment: not help and related

Comment: I encountered a similar problem using cmd.exe. What solved by problem was deleting the whole `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` key from the registry.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at eg https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/wiki/Sample-config:

according this file you can create a file ~/.config/psysh/config.php
and enter the color mode you like:

```
<?php
    return [ 'colorMode' => Psy\Configuration::COLOR_MODE_AUTO ] ;
```

Answer (score -1):

The recommended approach is to use a Unix terminal emulator, like Cygwin, Cmder or Babun.
https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/wiki/Windows

You could try to update the configuration of Psy by using:

"Psy\Configuration::COLOR_MODE_FORCED" or disable with 
"Psy\Configuration::COLOR_MODE_DISABLED".

Comment: How or where do you configure that?

Answer (score -2):

```sh
# On line ~37 of file 'vendor/psy/psysh/src/Configuration.php'
# const COLOR_MODE_DISABLED = 'disabled';
#turn it to 'auto'

#Changed
const COLOR_MODE_DISABLED = 'auto';
```