# Vim solarized colorscheme not displaying correctly in VS Code integrated terminal

Tags: user-interface, vim, terminal, visual-studio-code

#### Issue

Vim with solarized colorscheme is not displaying correctly in VS Code integrated terminal.

#### Details

I'm using the solarized colorscheme from https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.

When working in VSCode, Vim will open in the integrated terminal when I'm writing git commit messages, but the colors will be off.

I have tried playing around with different values for `t_Co`:

When `t_Co` is set to `16`:
[image: Vim with t_Co set to 16]

When `t_Co` is set to `8`:
[image: Vim with t_Co set to 8]

#### Edit:

Seems like it's not possible to easily configure VS Code's terminal colorscheme. A temporary workaround is to set `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` and let the solarized colorscheme use VS Code's theme.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, because I have no idea how VS code integrated terminal works, but have you put the relevant lines in your .vimrc to make solarized work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the `README` of the Solarized repo?

> If you are going to use Solarized in Terminal mode (i.e. not in a GUI version like gvim or macvim), please please please consider setting your terminal emulator's colorscheme to used the Solarized palette. I've included palettes for some popular terminal emulator as well as Xdefaults in the official Solarized download available from Solarized homepage. If you use Solarized without these colors, Solarized will need to be told to degrade its colorscheme to a set compatible with the limited 256 terminal palette (whereas by using the terminal's 16 ansi color values, you can set the correct, specific values for the Solarized palette).

You're probably going to have to set those colors manually, see: [Color theme for VS Code integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! This was what I did some time back when initially setting up solarized in the terminal. I'll try exploring this further.

Comment: If you at some point feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

I had a issue with text not showing after doing a "git commit" but it happens any time I tried to open a vim window inside terminal. A workaround was just to click the "Debug Console" and back to "Terminal" to get it to load the text properly.