# How to Fix Color Change Node Terminal ( Visual Studio Code after Oct. 2019 update)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A fews days ago, Visual Studio Code (Windows 10) updated itself. After that, the background and font colors in the terminal for `node` have changed to an annoying color scheme that is hard to read (see screenshot below). As long as the terminal stays in `powershell`, everything looks good. Note: The color scheme within the code editor itself is just fine.

Q: How or where do I fix the color scheme in VS Code for the node terminal?

[image: VS Code Terminal for node]

PS: The colors in the screenshot are "as is" - I have not selected the text. That's how it shows up.

Comment: BTW: This solution does not resolve my current issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Edit: Nevermind find the solution is using legacy mode