# How can I Customize Visual Studio Code terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I customize my Visual Studio Code terminal so that it looks like this?

[image]

My current terminal

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color theme for VS Code integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal)

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is to change the color of the integrated terminal. Mine terminal is complete different

Comment: What kind of terminal are you referring to then?

Comment: I have shown in the question

Comment: The image of the terminal in the question is a picture of the integrated terminal. And my duplicate question has a solution for the integrated terminal. So I do not get the difference you're referring to.

Comment: In your question, only the color of the terminal is changing but I don't want to change the color only I want to change the default PowerShell terminal to git bash terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the look of the integrated terminal in VS Code, you will need to edit the `settings.json` file. This is how you can access the file:

Windows/Linux: *File > Preference > Settings* . Alternatively, you can press `ctrl + shift + P` to open `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

MacOs: *Code > Preferences > Settings*. Alternatively, you can press:

- Shortcut (⌘)
- Search (⇧⌘P) → “Preferences: Open Settings”

Then search for *Workbench > Appearance > Color Customizations*. You will find your `settings.json` file. Make edits on the file.

You will find:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        # Add your theme here    
    }
```

Example themes can be:

```
      "terminal.background":"#1D2021",
      "terminal.foreground":"#A89984",
      "terminalCursor.background":"#A89984",
      "terminalCursor.foreground":"#A89984",
      "terminal.ansiBlack":"#1D2021",
      "terminal.ansiBlue":"#0D6678",
      "terminal.ansiBrightBlack":"#665C54",
      "terminal.ansiBrightBlue":"#0D6678",
      "terminal.ansiBrightCyan":"#8BA59B",
      "terminal.ansiBrightGreen":"#95C085",
      "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta":"#8F4673",
      "terminal.ansiBrightRed":"#FB543F",
      "terminal.ansiBrightWhite":"#FDF4C1",
      "terminal.ansiBrightYellow":"#FAC03B",
      "terminal.ansiCyan":"#8BA59B",
      "terminal.ansiGreen":"#95C085",
      "terminal.ansiMagenta":"#8F4673",
      "terminal.ansiRed":"#FB543F",
      "terminal.ansiWhite":"#A89984",
      "terminal.ansiYellow":"#FAC03B"
```

Find customization documentation from VS Code [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color). More [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#integrated-terminal-colors)

Comment: It will only change the color of the terminal.Please tell me how can I make my terminal look like the picture which I have given in the question

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the first screenshot, this should be taken from a Linux or MacOS terminal with the [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) framework installed. This framework allows custom theming to the terminal. Unfortunately, this framework is exclusive to Z shell terminals, which are only available on Linux and MacOS.

Fortunately, there's a workaround for Windows users. Windows has introduced the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) that allows you to run Linux on your Windows. Please [read the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) to learn how to install WSL system on your Windows. After installing WSL on your system, [check out this guide](https://blog.joaograssi.com/windows-subsystem-for-linux-with-oh-my-zsh-conemu/) that shows the steps of installing Z Shell on your WSL system and install Oh My Zsh framework in the shell.

Finally, go to VS Code and set the default terminal to be your WSL Z shell Terminal. You may check out [this short article](https://winsmarts.com/run-oh-my-zsh-as-integrated-shell-in-vscode-on-windows-7d69f72bafa3) for more details.