# Terminal highlighting in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run ls from my home directory, the list of files and directories  is displayed in various colors and some directories have a background color. I understand the filenames are displayed in whilte, while directories are blue.

What does a background color (green) behind a directory name indicate?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Blue text with green background indicates that a directory is writable by others apart from the owning user and group, and does not have the sticky bit set