# How do I change color of terminal prompt in Visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors

My current terminal has white prompt and white output
like this one https://vscode.one/img/terminal-font-size/terminal-font-size.gif
I Saw this thread about changing terminal color [Color theme for VS Code integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal)

Foreground changes the color of entire text, but I just want to see color different between the path and output. Similar to this one

[image]

The output is white and the path is other color.

Comment: Are you using a git bash terminal? This is what the default colors of the git bash terminal are.

Comment: git bash terminal is what I want to change to

Comment: For bash and zsh you can customize the prompt text which will carry over into vscode here is a video https://youtu.be/p4h-5B8k2NY

Comment: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c141.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then search and `Open User Setting (JSON)`
2. Paste the JSON settings below to change basic colors

   ```
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "terminal.background": "#2C3E50",
      "terminal.foreground": "#E0E0E0",
    }
   ```
3. For a higher level of colour customizations, you can use this [Terminal Colors Generator](https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term/#/). It will create `JSON` with all colours you selected and just paste it into your settings JSON.