# Git Bash in VS Code doesn't display all colors correctly

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-bash, mintty

## Problem

I'm using git bash in Visual Studio Code and it doesn't seem to work perfectly. By enabling `terminal.integrated.windowsEnableConpty` I could at least get rid of all the escaped color codes - but at the end it doesn't seem to be correct.

*Git Bash doesn't show correct colors*
[image]

*PowerShell shows correct colors*
[image: Windows PowerShell in vscode]

## settings.json

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
  "terminal.integrated.windowsEnableConpty": true,
  "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom"
}
```

## Versions

Both are using the latest versions.

```sh
# visual studio code version
Version: 1.49.2 (system setup)
Commit: e5e9e69aed6e1984f7499b7af85b3d05f9a6883a
Date: 2020-09-24T16:29:41.983Z
Electron: 9.2.1
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041
```

```sh
# git version
git version 2.28.0.windows.1
```

Is there someone who could help?

Comment: You can get some ideas from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57020162/15492071