# Why doesn't my integrated VS Code Bash terminal use bash coloring?

Tags: windows, bash, git, visual-studio-code

When I'm using VS Code's integrated bash terminal I don't have any of the normal bash coloring schemes, all of my text is simply white.  If I use git bash outside of VS Code, I get all of the normal directory colorings.

I tried the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102657/bash-terminal-colors-in-integrated-terminal-in-vs-code) as well as the others mentioned in the same post but nothing worked.  I also made sure to have my bash terminal profile set to the correct exe file but that hasn't worked either.  I've also read through VS Code's new documentation on terminal profiles but I think mine is set up correctly.  I don't know what else to check at this point, everything looks to be correct.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Here are my terminal settings:

```
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
        }
    }
```

Here is a picture showing Git Bash, VS Code's settings, and my VS Code Bash terminal.
[image]

**Bash inside VSC:**

```
$ echo $COLORTERM
truecolor
$ echo $PS1
\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

**Bash outside VSC:**

```
$ echo $COLORTERM

$ echo $PS1
\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$
$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

Comment: have you tried a different theme, if they don't specify the terminal colors, I use `Default Light+` and it uses colors in Git Bash (you have to customize the colors a few shades darker), `One Dark Pro` too I think

Comment: Yes, I tried changing my VS Code theme but it didn't make a difference.  I'm using `Monokai` and switched to `Light + (default Light)` but the terminal stayed the same.

Comment: what is the value of environment variables: `COLORTERM` and `PS1` inside the VSC terminal

Comment: @rioV8 Where would I check these?  I haven't seen something like this before.

Comment: **environment variables** : `set`

Comment: @rioV8 In settings.json?  If so, I don't see any references to environment variables.

Comment: what does `${env:windir}` mean in your settings

Comment: tbh, I'm not too sure.  I was trying to set up terminal profiles because that's what VS Code docs recommended.  I thought if I specifically told VS code where to look for the bash.exe file it would start using the right color scheme.

Comment: it is determined by the configuration of the shell

Comment: Run `echo $COLORTERM`, `echo $PS1`, and `echo $TERM` inside the VSCode terminal. Compare them to what gets printed outside VSCode. Are they the same or is something different?

Comment: @JohnKugelman If I echo out what you're asking for, I get back the same thing inside VSC and the CMD prompt outside of VSC.  Do I just pull up a regular cmd terminal in VSC and type "echo $COLORTERM" etc.?

Comment: In the image you compare Git Bash with VSC terminal and you type commands in windows cmd terminal

Comment: You're asking about the Bash terminals, so in the two bash terminals you're asking about, not in cmd!

Comment: The visual appearance of your prompt, including colouring, is determined by the value of `PS1`. We're asking to show us what `echo $PS1` outputs in your two terminals, so that we can see how you're configured. `COLORTERM` and `TERM` also have an impact, so showing those as well will help.

Comment: @joanis I put everything you asked for in the question.

Comment: Thanks! And darn... that's exactly like on my computer, yet I get colors correctly in both Git Bash and in VSCode bash terminal. So we're back to your VSCode config - your Bash settings are set correctly, but I have no idea what VSCode setting might cause this, sorry!

Comment: One thing you can try is delete your settings.json file (keep a backup first!) and try to restore VSCode defaults. Mine has nearly no customizations, so the defaults should have the colors correctly. If the colors work then, put back in one thing or block at a time until you figure out what line is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working!  I took @joanis's advice and started resetting chunks of my VSC settings and narrowed it down to the **Minimum Contrast Ratio** setting.  I don't know why but mine was set at 21.  The default is 4.5.  Once I changed mine to default, the git bash terminal colors showed up!

[image]
[image]